# Remote control graphical Firefox instance

Tags: bash, firefox, browser, automation, desktop

Is there any way to control regular Firefox instance remotely? I'm not looking for automated web testing or anything else utilizing headless browser. **I'd just like to make useful CLI and desktop gadgets to improve browsing experience**, in particular small shell or Python scripts (or JavaScript if there's no other choice). But **they must run outside of browser** and conduct their operations over platform and language independent API (so basically over some socket).

For instance, I'd like to make a Bash script that will print URLs of open tabs to standard output. Or move all tabs on domain X to a new window. There are many APIs available to extensions that make such tasks possible. I would like to use these (or similar) APIs outside of extension context. This could be done by having all-powerful super-extensions that would proxy outside requests over https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging. There are also https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer and Selenium albeit developed primarily for headless usage. It seems there used to be D-Bus API, but I don't see any Firefox service exposed when running Firefox 69.

What are some flexible ways to script Firefox for a shell junkie?

NOTE: I'm aware of security risks coming from opening Firefox debugger port which some aforementioned tools require.